# Convert character argument with multiple conditional statements into logical to subset in a function independent of dataframe name

Tags: r

***Statement of problem:*** I am creating a function that needs to subset the data based on sub-population (subpop) arguments provided by the user; one or more conditions may be supplied as a character, e.g., `subpop = "sex ==1 & race4 == 2"`.

The relevant function (excerpts) looks something like:

```
collapse = function(data, subpop,...) {
data2 = subset(data, subpop[1])
...
}
```

***Sample dataset created with the*** `dput` ***function***:

```
    structure(list(sex = structure(c(0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 
1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), labels = c(male = 0, female = 1
), class = "labelled"), race4 = structure(c(2, 3, 3, 1, 2, 2, 
2, 2, 1, 3, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 2, 1, 2, 2), labels = c(MexAm = 1, 
white = 2, black = 3, other = 4), class = "labelled")), row.names = c(NA, 
-20L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

***My attempts so far:*** I can easily subset the data if I supplied the arguments as a logical statement directly rather than passing it through an object.

```
> data2 = subset(data, sex ==1 & race4 == 2) #Attempt 1: Works
> dim(data2)
[1] 3 2

> subpop <- "sex ==1 & race4 == 2" #Attempt 2: Does not work
> y = with(data, subpop[1])
> data2 = subset(data, y)
Error in subset.data.frame(data, y) : 'subset' must be logical

> y = with(data, subpop[1]) #Attempt 3: Does not work; empty rows 
> data2 = subset(data, as.logical(y))
> dim(data2)
[1] 0 2

> data2=data[which(is.logical(subpop[1])),] #Attempt 4: Does not work; empty rows
> dim(data2)
[1] 0 2

> data2 = subset(data, pander::evals(subpop)) #Attempt 5: Does not work
Error in subset.data.frame(n, evals(subpop)) : 'subset' must be logical

> eval(parse(text == subpop)) #Attempt 6: Does not work
Error in parse(text == subpop) : unused argument (text == subpop)
```

These are just a few of dozens of code I have tried. Over the past few days, I have combed through countless forums, discussions, and posts, but can't find something. Maybe I am missing something somewhere. This is my first post on this forum and I really hope someone will help me out here.

The fundamental issue here is that I can't seem to be able to get R to recognize the contents of the subgroup object as a logical statement, no matter what I do.

***Summary***: How do I pass an object containing a set of conditions so that R can use the contents of that object to subset. The number of conditions may be very variable in their number, format, or types of operators used (e.g., "==", "%in%", ">=", etc). There is no way of knowing this a priori, as such, I need to pass those conditions via an object rather than directly. Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
> subset(df, sex ==1 & race4 == 2)
   sex race4
5    1     2
8    1     2
13   1     2
```

Approach I using logical object:

```
# Create a logical object
> l<-df$sex ==1 & df$race4 == 2

> str(l) # check structure of 'l'
 logi [1:20] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE TRUE FALSE ...

> subset(df,l)
   sex race4
5    1     2
8    1     2
13   1     2
```

Approach II using character object:

```
> a<-"sex ==1 & race4 == 2"
> subset(df, eval(parse(text=a)))
> sex race4
  5    1     2
  8    1     2
  13   1     2
```

Comment: Wow! Many thanks @rar. Does this mean that in creating a logical object, I MUST include a reference to the dataframe? e.g.,  l<-df$sex ==1 & df$race4 == 2 rather than  l<- "sex ==1 & race4 == 2". My earlier attempts were focused on creating a character object rather than a logical object. If I had such a character object, is there any way to convert it to logical? Warm regards.

Comment: @Ter: I have updated the reply. If this answers your query, please accept the answer.

Comment: Thanks. I have accepted the answer, but have one last question. The second code you provided (string argument) works well for me in regular R but not in R studio. In the latter, I get the following error for this command:     > subpop = "race4 ==1 & sex ==1"
> data1 = subset(data, eval(parse(text = subpop)))
Error in parse(text = subpop) : unused argument (text = subpop). Thoughts?

Comment: @Ter: That is strange because for me it works well in R studio as well. Sorry can't really comment on this.

Comment: No worries. You are a lifesaver; I will use the first approach with a logical object. Greatly appreciate your time.